Ubuntu 22.04 is stuck at a black screen
I restarted the PC, and then Ubuntu froze at this boot screen. It's still stuck here after 5 minutes:


It appears your graphics display is on a different monitor than the one you show. What happens when you press  +  + ? Does that bring you to a login terminal? Please Edit your question to include this information.
